# SAS: Summing across rows conditional on date in each row

Tags: sas

I have the information shown in the first four columns in the table below and would like to add the column **Calls_previous_3_days** containing the sum of calls from each CustID to each Area the previous three dates.

I.e., if a custumer made a call to Support on 17Jan2015 I would like the new variable to show the sum of the number of calls that the customer made to Support during the period 14Jan2015-16Jan2015.

How do I calculate the sum in the column **Calls_previous_3_days** dependent on the CustID, Area and Date?

```
CustID  Area     Date       Calls   Calls_previous_3_days
3137    Support  05Jan2015  1       0
3137    Support  14Jan2015  4       0 
3137    Support  16Jan2015  1       4
3137    Support  17Jan2015  1       5
3137    Support  20Jan2015  2       1
3137    Support  22Jan2015  1       2
5225    Support  26Jan2015  1       0
5225    Support  27Jan2015  1       1
5225    Support  28Jan2015  1       2
5225    Sales    14Feb2015  1       0       
5225    Sales    15Feb2015  1       1
5225    Sales    22Feb2015  1       0
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking up the `lag` function - that should be a good starting point. [Link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with arrays, by storing the last three values and dates and then summing where the dates satisfy your criteria.

```
proc sort data = have;
    by CustID Area;;
run;
proc print;
data want;
    set have;
    by CustID Area;
    /* Create temporary array (which automatically retains) */
    array hist{3,2} _temporary_;
    /* Initialise the array values if starting a new group */
    if first.Area then call missing(of hist[*]);
    /* Sum the values in the array that satisfy your condition */
    callsp3 = sum(
        0,
        (sum(Date, - hist[1,2]) <= 3) * hist[1,1],
        (sum(Date, - hist[2,2]) <= 3) * hist[2,1],
        (sum(Date, - hist[3,2]) <= 3) * hist[3,1]
    );
    /* Store the current value/date in the array and shift old values down */
    hist[1,1] = hist[2,1];
    hist[1,2] = hist[2,2];
    hist[2,1] = hist[3,1];
    hist[2,2] = hist[3,2];
    hist[3,1] = Calls;
    hist[3,2] = Date;
run;
```

---

There are (as always with SAS) several ways to approach this problem. You could also investigate the [`lag()` functions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm) or use `proc sql` to self join the data with an `on` clause like to specify your condition. I prefer the array approach as `lag()` has some [*gotchas*](http://www.howles.com/saspapers/CC33.pdf) and self joining will be slower. However, if it is likely that you will want different or longer windows then the array approach can become somewhat unwieldy due to the length of the code. This can be mitigated if you are confident in the macro language, but it may then be better to investigate a different approach.

---

If you have SAS/ETS licensed you should be able to achieve this with `proc expand`. I cannot confirm this does exactly what you want though as I don't have a licence.

```
proc expand data = have out = want from = day to = day;
    by CustID Area;
    id Date;
    convert calls = callsp3 / method = none transformout = (movsum 4);
run;
data want; 
    set want (where = (calls ~= .));
    callsp3 = callsp3 - calls;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I do not have much experience with arrays, but your suggestion certainly works so that might be something I should look into. I also need to calculate the same thing looking 7 dates back instead of just 3. I'm not quite sure how to adjust your code suggest for the 3 days I asked about in the first place.

Comment: By the way, I also tried the 'proc expand' code you suggested. Given the CustID and Area it just sums the Calls for the current row and the two previous rows, which are not necessarily within the three days previous to the date of the current row, which I was looking for.

Comment: I've made a change to the `proc expand` suggestion which should correct for including the current day, and maybe the date alignment. To adjust the array approach to 7 days you would need to expand the array definition (`hist{7,2}`), add extra lines to the sum (for `hist[4,x]` upwards), amend the condition in the sum components (`<= 7`) and add extra lines for shifting the values down the array.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a go with the array and managed to make the required adjustments just prior to you comment. I know fully understand your comment about the code becomming "unwieldy due to the length of the code" :- ) Unfortunately, I would not be able to write the generic code required for macro for any possible duration. In the line `array hist{7,2} _temporary` does the value 2 just imply the second colums to the right of the columns named in the by statement?

Comment: Well done. The macro wrapper would not be a bad exercise if you ever felt like learning how to use macro `%do` loops. The second digit in the array definition describes the number of elements in the [second dimension](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000739621.htm) of the array. Think of this array as a table with 7 columns and 2 rows, in the second row (referenced `hist[x,2]`) we are storing the dates for the comparisons in the sum.

Comment: Regarding the expand code the first step now outputs a dataset with a row for every date. The column `callsp3` now contains values on dates in the original table and the following 3 dates. Though, the summed value includes the number of call on the current day. However, the calls of the current day can be subtracted to get the sum of the previous 3 dates. The column  `Calls` holds the the value of the next observation from the original table for all the inserted rows (dates not in the original table). In step 2 I get an error from `callsp3 - calls`.

Comment: If I could get the proc expand to work I could easily make that into a makro. I have, however, one concern. Having millions of customers in my call database, the prox expand would add an huge amount of rows in my dataset as it would practically make a row for every day of the year for each customer.

Comment: That would make it a very inefficient option. You're unlikely to beat the array approach for speed.

Answer (score 0):

The LAG function, as @SRSwift detailed, certainly works well.

Also, here is a SQL solution. Used a Data Step to substitute 0 for missing, not sure if a CASE statement in the SQL step would be the best way to do this or not.

```
Data HAVE;
Input custid $ area $ date:date9. calls;
format date date9.;
datalines;
3137    Support  05Jan2015  1
3137    Support  14Jan2015  4
3137    Support  16Jan2015  1
3137    Support  17Jan2015  1
3137    Support  20Jan2015  2
3137    Support  22Jan2015  1
5225    Support  26Jan2015  1
5225    Support  27Jan2015  1
5225    Support  28Jan2015  1
5225    Sales    14Feb2015  1
5225    Sales    15Feb2015  1
5225    Sales    22Feb2015  1
;
Run;

Proc sql;
Create table WANT as
Select custid,area,date,calls,
(select sum(calls) from have b where a.custid=b.custid and 
  a.area=a.area and (a.date-3<=b.date<a.date)) as Calls_Previous_3_Days
From HAVE a;
Quit;

Data WANT;
Set WANT;
If missing(calls_previous_3_days) then Calls_Previous_3_Days=0;
Run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was nice to see an SQL solution as well.